# Drip watering 5m flower bed from downpipe

Tags: watering, irrigation

I have a 5m flowerbed at the front of my house that is under roof cover and so gets no direct rain onto it. Beside it is the downpipe from the roof guttering and I can't help but wonder if I could just feed a single 5m tube/piping from that with tiny holes to drip water the flowers.

I have 2 questions;

1. Does something like this exist already? I've found this type of part which appears to direct water into a tank: https://www.tanks-direct.co.uk/black-rainwater-filter-collector-2000840.html?fee=3&fep=1565&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIraHxo9rc6gIVSLDtCh3NBgSmEAQYAiABEgLjI_D_BwE

[image]

I wonder if I could just attach a hose to that and pierce some tiny holes all along it?

2. If I did use something like the above, should I be worried about the volume of water coming down the downpipe and flooding the flower bed, and what happens when the hose fills up because there is more water entering it than is leaving via the tiny holes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems reasonable, however, it might tend to clog up/ provide inconsistent water distribution a lot. And maybe check to be sure the roof runoff wouldn't have tar or nutrients poor for the flowers etc. If unimpeded it would be inappropriate during a heavy rain. Regulating the water would be problematical, even if it didn't clog up, just as in regular rainfall.

Comment: Depending on type and proximity  of trees, the jets should plug quickly.

Comment: yes indeeed! and plug at different rates! thank you for your kind comment!